# Why doesn't typescript enforce my class to be instantiated with correct types?

Tags: typescript

I wanted to play around with TypeScript and made a surprising (to me!) observation. My impression was that TypeScript would enforce strong typing for all of my code that uses type annotations. But that doesn't seem to be the case.

Why does TypeScript allow me to instantiate `Car` with the wrong type here?

```
class Engine {}

class Tires {}

class MockEngine {}

class Car {
  engine: Engine;
  tires: Tires;

  constructor(engine: Engine, tires: Tires) {
    this.engine = engine;
    this.tires = tires;
    alert("foo");
  }
}

let car = new Car("foo", new Tires());
let car2 = new Car(7, new Tires());
let car3 = new Car(new MockEngine(), new Tires());
```

[Runnable Code](http://goo.gl/4WY1iw)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type matching/associations in TypeScript are not based upon the name of the class/interface, but instead based upon the signature. And by having empty class definitions you are basically saying that they are of any type, but just adding `displacement: number;` to the Engine class will break your code below.

```
// consider this:
class Foo {
  foo: string;
}
class Bar {
  constructor(private foo: Foo){}
}

var b1 = new Bar(new Foo()); // valid
var b2 = new Bar({}); // invalid
var b3 = new Bar({foo: 'val'}); // valid
```

[See above code in the TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=%20%20%20%20class%20Foo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20class%20Bar%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20foo%3A%20Foo)%7B%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20var%20b1%20%3D%20new%20Bar(new%20Foo())%3B%20%2F%2F%20valid%0A%09var%20b2%20%3D%20new%20Bar(%7B%7D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20invalid%0A%09var%20b3%20%3D%20new%20Bar(%7Bfoo%3A%20'val'%7D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20valid)

Comment: Tip: And how you can see in Brocco example, you can save typing a lot of code by just putting a "private" or "public" prefix before each argument, so this automatically define class properties and assign arguments to properties.